# Auto refresh for infinite times after page loads

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, refresh, auto

I'm looking for a auto refresher, but it shouldn't work on time intervals. It needs to reload every time after the page loads, for the infinite times.

Please help me if there any thing that would work.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to reload it once after every page load? And that should work on the next infinite number of page loads? Is that the question

Comment: How is this related to both `java` and `javascript`? Pick one!

Comment: @NikhilSingh, Hello, page loads then reload, and keeps repeating this step.
reload after page loads, not in time intervals... Please help.

Comment: I get it, can you tell the exact issue there might be some alternate way to approach the problem

Comment: I'm looking for a way or script, that loads a url, and reloads after fully loads. And this cycle goes on for infinity...